# How do I define an ARRAY column in a Sequel Postgresql migration?

Tags: ruby, database, postgresql, migration, sequel

I am creating a Sequel migration to create a new table in my PostgreSQL database. I want to define a [String array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/arrays.html#AEN6033) column, which PostgreSQL supports.

My migration looks like this:

```
create_table :venues do
  primary_key :id

  String      :reference                                , :null => false
  String      :name                                     , :null => false
  String      :description                              , :null => false
  String[]    :type                                     , :null => false

  DateTime    :created_at                               , :null => false
  DateTime    :updated_at                               , :null => false
end
```

How can I define something like `text[]` in my migration?

Answer (score 22):

You just use the column method and specify the type as a string: `column :type, "text[]"`

Comment: Look here for the syntax http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/schema_modification_rdoc.html#label-Column+types