# How to save array in database correctly?

Tags: arrays, ruby, database, postgresql, sequel

I want to add array in database. I use [ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), [sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) and [postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/), but question about true way, and not program realization.
I see 3 path:

1. Use special [adapters](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/pg_array_rb.html). It help to save array like `[1,2,3,4]` in db after some changes: in database it [will look like](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html) `"{1,2,3,4}"`. BUT after it I don't know how to convert this entry back to `[1,2,3,4]` without bullshits.
2. Convert array to json and save it to database. Array like `[1,2,3,4]` will be look like `"[1,2,3,4]"`. And I can easy convert back by `JSON.parse`.
3. Convert array by [Marshal](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Marshal.html) and save. Array `[1,2,3,4]` will be look like `"\x04\b[\ti\x06i\ai\bi\t"`, but it riskily, because data can be changed after ruby update (or I am wrong)
   Can anybody to tell about true way?

Comment: PostgreSQL has a JSON field type and `sequel` has an ability to store/load to/from there in a natural way without any explicit marshalling. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html

Comment: @mudasobwa yes, but it correctly to save array to database like json? If you tell about http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/pg_json_rb.html - it is look like first variant in my question, but with json conversion instead array

Comment: I am not sure I follow. You have in ruby a field of type postgres json, assign it like `user.roles = %w|admin poster commenter|` and save it within all others like `user.save!` and/or `user.update_attributes!(roles: ...)`. Everything else is done by sequel/postgres.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784259/how-to-declare-postgresql-json-jsonb-field-with-sequel

Comment: If there is a small chance that you need to query your data by an array element in the future then I suggest with Postgresql's array extension or an extra table.

Comment: @spickermann extra table is good idea, but in my case it not necessary. I will not use searching by this field

Comment: @mudasobwa Variant with %w|admin poster commenter| in field with json type is work, but then need to JSON.parse() this field to getting array instead string ("[1,2,3,4,5]")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequel supports Postgres Array columns natively, assuming you don’t need to normalize yourschema further.

[How do I define an ARRAY column in a Sequel Postgresql migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677924/how-do-i-define-an-array-column-in-a-sequel-postgresql-migration)

http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/pg_array_rb.html

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, The clean approach would be an extra table. Ideally, each row in the DB represent a single observation, and having an array or json column most probably contradicts that. I suggest looking at that extra table as good design, not as an overkill.

Answer (score -1):

Make use of [serialize](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class) provided by ActiveRecord

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  serialize :preferences, Array

end


#In migration Add a string field
class AddSerializePreferencesToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :preferences, :string
  end
end

#In rails console.

u = User.first
u.preferences # => []
u.preferences << 'keep coding' 
u.preferences # => ['keep coding']
u.save
u.reload.preferences #  ['keep coding']
```

Hope this helps

Comment: He’s using Sequel gem not ActiveRecord.